# System.TypeInitializationException while opening word with openxml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I get a **System.TypeInitializationException** while opening a word document with openxml from an asp.net (MVC) application. This code has been working fine. Possibliy some very recent windows 10 update is the problem. Code works on server, but not anymore on my windows 10 machine.  Mehtod:

```
WordprocessingDocument.Open(officeDocument, false);
```

officeDocument is a *MemoryStream*. The innermost Exception (System.Security Exception, Der angeforderte Registrierungszugriff ist unzulässig.) :

```
   bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
   bei Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   bei Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(String keyName, String valueName, Object defaultValue)
   bei MS.Utility.EventTrace.IsClassicETWRegistryEnabled()
   bei MS.Utility.EventTrace..cctor()
```

The outer Exception (Der Typeninitialisierer für \"MS.Utility.EventTrace\" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht.}   System.TypeInitializationException
):

```
   bei MS.Utility.EventTrace.EasyTraceEvent(Keyword keywords, Event eventID)
   bei System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
   bei DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
   bei DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
```

Comment: Exactly same error accessing performance counters, saw it today for the very first time (but I didn't find any relevant just installed update)

Comment: Just an educated guess because I had a similar problem years ago: To me it looks like the code behind `WordprocessingDocument.Open` tries to write stuff to the event-log. Maybe the log target does not exist for some reason so the code automatically tries to create it resulting in creation of a new registry key. If now the process does not have the respective permission, this might lead to the failure. What happens if you run the application again with administrative permissions once and then with restricted permissions again afterwards?

Comment: @Peit Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I did run the code outside of IIS and it runs fine. But

Comment: @Peit Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I did run the code outside of IIS and it runs fine. Somehow it will not work. I did consult the source code and the key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Avalon.Graphics\\. How can I give IIS ApplicationPoolIdentity the rights to create this key?

Comment: At least I got it running again. In App-Pool settings, I changed Identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem. Still don't know why it suddently stopped working. Probably security changes from my company (it is a big one) or security patches or whatever